# Nested object field names concatenation using colon(:)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm working on custom in memory configuration provider. And to do so, first I have to be able to convert nested settings into colon separated keys and values so that I can read it using IConfigurationRoot. So, is there an extension or something I can use to automatically convert any object lets say

```
public class Person{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public Contact Contact {get; set;}
} 
public class Contact{
  public string Email {get; set;}
  public string Phone {get; set;}
}
```

to the following format

```
Dictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
settings.Add("Person:Name", "Jack");
settings.Add("Person:Contact:Email", "jack@gmail.com");
```

Comment: `settings.Add("Person:Gender", 1);` is not assignable to `Dictionary<string, string>`. 1 is not a string. Also, you need to consider cases, where a nested object is either an array or a Collection. What should be the expected output in case of collection or array?

Comment: @Navjot Singh Thanks for reaching out. Yeap, I will fix that I was just trying to give an example. The expected objects are objects that are similar to what we can found in appsettings.json.